# How to click on checkbox buttons in a Pop-up window with Selenium WebDriver- Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[screen shoot of the pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jINJH.png)

I need to focus on the pop up window and select the checkboxes.(screenshot is attached)

I tried to define the browser to accept every popup window that will show up.

```
def update_firefox_profile():
      profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
      profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
      profile.assume_untrusted_cert_issuer = False
      profile.update_preferences()
      return profile
```

Do you have another idea?
Thank you !

Comment: Since browser popup's are infact alerts, you can focus on them using `webdriver.switch_to_alert()`

Comment: OK after I use the function you wrote, how can I click on the checkboxes (as shown in the screenshot) ?

Comment: This is a browser dialog and not a JS alert. Your best bet would be to google this particular dialog and find the preferences you can set on the driver to take care of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this is a web pop or windows pop up. If it's a web popup then try to inspect the elements on the pop up to select the desired checkbox. Incase of windows pop up, you can use AutoIT script. Another approach will be using import java.awt.Robot. Using Robot class, you can send Keyboard events to select the desired checkbox and click on the submit button. But in this case, you should assume that the sequence of checkboxes will be same.